Irreducible components of the common zeros of $x^2-yz$ and $y^2-xz$.
One must find the irreducible components in the Zariski Topology of the common zeros of $x^2-yz$ and $y^2-xz$. The question states that there are $4$, but I only find $2$.
I would say that a decomposition of the first set of zeros is $(x,y,x^2/y)$ for $y\neq 0$, union with $(0,0,z)$; and for the second $(x,y,y^2/x)$, $x \neq 0$, union with $(0,0,z)$, where the free variables go over the field $k$. Then the intersection of those unions gives us a union of irreducible components:
$(0,0,z)$ and $(x,x,x)$. This cannot be, since there should be $4$. Where did I go wrong?

I get $(0:0:1),(1:1:1),(\pm\frac2{\sqrt3i\mp1}:\mp\frac2{\sqrt3 i\pm1}:1),$ i.e. four solutions as two conics in ${\Bbb P}^2_{\Bbb C}$ should have by Bezout.

So I'm missing those last two solutions, but I'm not catching where I missed them in my argument...

Ah, I got it, I used the fact that x^3 = y^3 as implying only x=y, I ignored two solutions there. I think that does it.

@Jan-MagnusØkland Would it be possible for you to post that as an answer?

I believe you need some restrictions on the field. If the characteristic is $3$ then $x^3=y^3$ does imply $x=y$. So I guess you exclude that case.

Yes, the characteristic of the field is not 3.

The observation OP made in the comments is correct, $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2),$ so $(0:0:1),(1:1:1),(\pm\frac2{\sqrt3i\mp1}:\mp\frac2{\sqrt3 i+1}:1),$ i.e. four solutions as two conics in ${\Bbb P}^2_{\Bbb C}$ should have by Bezout.
